# Azure Automation diagnostics not saved

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics

What I'm trying to create is a solution where we have an Azure Automation account running some scripts and that the error messages generated from the jobs are saved in an Azure resource where we can setup alerts and analyze the errors.

The Azure Automation account is setup and I can create jobs properly. I added a diagnostics settings that sends to log analytics workspace all the JobLogs, JobStreams and AllMetrics. But when I open the Log Analytics workspace the Logs view there shows nothing and the Related Resources\Automation Account simply says that nothing is connected.

I have been reading through A LOT of documentation but I have not been able to find any clear guide at all of how to connect everything together in 2019 especially when they keep changing everything on Azure all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics) should be the document that you are looking for to forward joblogs, jobstreams, dscnodestatus, allmetrics from Azure Automation to Azure monitor logs.

After you have enabled it, you may also double check it by using [Get-AzDiagnosticSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-2.4.0) cmdlet as explained in the same above mentioned document. Or else you may go to Azure portal -> Your Automation Account -> Diagnostics settings tile -> make sure joblogs, jobstreams, dscnodestatus, allmetrics are ticked.

I have followed the same instructions and could see the joblogs, jobstreams in the logs as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much! One very important thing that took me a while to realize is this line: "To see the logs, run the following query in log analytics log search: AzureDiagnostics | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION"" **AzureDiagnostics is one of the few if not the only table that actually contains data**

Comment: And if I have understood things correctly now the difference between running the queries against the automation account directly and the log analytics workspace is that the latter lets you setup alerts?

Comment: No. Both lets you setup alerts. The alert rules that are created from Automation Account (or any other service in this case) fall under Azure Monitor (i.e., these kind of alert rules are categorized as Metric signal type) but the alert rules that are created from Log Analytics fall under Log Analytics only (i.e., these kind of alert rules are categorized as Log signal type).